# Permission denied in FTP even though I'm the owner

Tags: permissions, ftp, ownership

Okay, so I've tried my best at finding the answer to this by searching and looking through possible duplicates, but I just can't so forgive me if it's out there somewhere anyways.

My issue is as follows. I've set the owner of `/var/www` to `myuser:www-data` and permissions of the folder and all (currently just the basic index.html) it's content to `750`, and Apache seems to run it as supposed, but I can't access it when I FTP into the server as the `myuser` user. I mean, I can access it, but as soon as I try to edit, delete or add something I just get `500 Permission denied`, and if I try to edit the permissions I get `500 Unknown SITE command`.

Help! What do I do wrong? The idea on setting the user and group, and then the permissions as above was from a good friend of mine who is sort of an expert, but I feel like I'm bothering him when I ask so many questions, so if you can help me some more, that would be great!

I'm trying to put a backup with 4 vhosts back into the www-folder, but what I put there shouldn't be of any concern, right? That's just the confing of the vhosting later that has got anything to do with that, right?

Thanks in advance!

Added info:

I ran this: 
    `myuser@myserver:/$ groups myuser`
And got this:
    `myuser : myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`
Then I ran this:
    `myuser@myserver:/$ groups www-data`
And got this:
    `www-data : www-data`

And then this:
    `myuser@myserver:/var/www$ ls -l`
And got this:
    `total 4`
    `-rwxr-x--- 1 tjita1 www-data 177 Jan 25 17:45 index.html`

Regarding the ftpserver, I didn't do anything in particular, I just installed vsftpd. Oh yeah, I also added a line in I think `/etc/vsftpd.conf` or something like that, that reads something like this: `chmod_enable=YES`.

Also, I can't get those 4-space-indents to work, sorry about that..

Comment: I don't know whether this is right, but messing with permissions of such a directory is not a good way. Anyhow, May I ask the output of `groups myuser` (as in; replace it with the username of the user) please? and also `ls -l` of `www` dir

Comment: How did you setup your ftp server?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

After you install the ftp server with `sudo apt-get install vsftpd` you will have to configure it. To enable write access you have to edit the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file and uncomment the

```
#write_enable=YES
```

line, so it should read

```
write_enable=YES
```

Save the file and restart `vsftpd` with `sudo service vsftpd restart`.

For other configuration options consult [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd) or [`man vsftpd.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/en/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html)

Comment: You are the man. This finally helped me!

Comment: And all the answers on the internet were wrong. Yet, so simple and plain. I even read teh vsftpd.conf just for fun!

Comment: Notice: after this make sure to kill current `vsftpd` process. Then restart it via `sudo service vsftpd start` to make it pick-up these new changes. Now, you will be able to connect via FTP and write/delete files.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way I found to use ftp with curl command [**here**](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/08/551-permission-denied-ftp.html). If you wanna use ftp with a single command than use the following command

```
sudo curl -T file_to_be_uploaded.txt ftp://mydomain.com/mydirectory/ --user username:password
```

If you get an error `551: permission denied` than run it the file you are uploading might be present on the remote and you don't have permission to overwrite it. So upload it with a different file name or delete the current file on the remote.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem & none of the suggestions about Write_enable or folder permissions worked.  I changed my connection type in my FTP client from FTP to SSH/SFTP, and everything worked fine.  Apparently, VSFTPD requires a secure connection to write.

Comment: If you used SFTP, then you're likely *not* using vsftpd, despite the name. FTPS is secure FTP, SFTP is the SSH File Transfer Protocol, and is usually handled by whichever SSH server is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Run below command - which folder you require files to upload

sudo chown -R <>:root <>
example

sudo chown -R myloginid:root /home/myproject